# Como faço para receber e apresentar dados sem fazer refresh da página?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boas, estou a criar um sistema de notificações na minha aplicação onde quero ir buscar dados à base de dados e informar o utilizador consoante os mesmos através de notificações. Acontece que estou um bocado perdido em como é que faço para que as notificações sejam actualizadas sem eu fazer um request de um form ou algo semelhante.

Alguém me consegue dar umas 'luzes' em como é que eu devo proceder? Estou um bocado perdido

UPDATE: 
Estou a tentar usar AJAX para o fazer e estou a tentar o seguinte código mas nada acontece:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<?=base_url("notificacoes")?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            key: 'olá'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Notificacoes extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        echo $this->input->post('key');
    }
}
```

A ideia é fazer um print da variável key quando a página faz load

Comment: Utilize-se e estude um pouco sobre requisições ajax

Comment: Já comecei a ver um pouco de ajax, entretanto, surgiu-me uma duvida e atualizei o post. Se me conseguir ajudar agradecia

Comment: Serviu, simplesmente surgiu-me uma duvida nova que está ligada com a resposta que me deram e, para nao estar a criar outro post, reeditei este

Comment: Sua função ajax não esta sendo chamada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De princípio no protocolo [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) o cliente faz a requisição e o servidor responde, logo, de alguma forma terás que fazer uma requisição. 
Mas existem algumas soluções, tais como:

- **[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)** - O Ajax te permite comunicar com o servidor sem ter que fazer refresh na página e para o tal terias que fazer requisição de x em x tempo, mas isso iria inundar o seu servidor de pedidos o que não é uma boa implementação.
- **[React](https://hackernoon.com/react-js-a-better-introduction-to-the-most-powerful-ui-library-ever-created-ecd96e8f4621)**– Com o React podes escolher o que actualizar no Dom através de
  componentes reativas que te permite interagir com elementos
  HTML específicos. E o codeIgniter já tem pacote ([CodeIgniter with React](https://github.com/kala725/CodeIgniter-with-React)) que te permite usar React.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Já comecei a ver um pouco de ajax, entretanto, surgiu-me uma duvida e atualizei o post. Se me conseguir ajudar agradecia

Comment: Não acontece nada porque talvez o Ajax não chega a ser chamada. Experimenta colocar o Ajax dentro do `window.onload(()=>{ $.ajax({
        url: '<?=base_url("notificacoes")?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            key: 'olá'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); })`

Answer (score 0):

**Pra ficar claro**: isso aqui não é um tutorial. Vc precisa ter familiaridade com a metodologia do framework.

O código proposto nesta resposta faz basicamente uma requisição `$_POST` pro `method` `json/index` passando os dados do `form` e trata a resposta para mostrar tudo num `alert`. **OBS:** em que pese vc tenha dito que não quer usar um `form`, vc vai ter que fazer a requisição de uma maneira ou de outra, então, eu usei um `form` pra organizar os dados. Aprofundando mais no `JQuery` vc vai aprender a extrair os dados de qualquer tipo de elemento pra enviar.

Considerando a estrutura do `CodeIgniter` constante da documentação, sugiro criar um `Controller` que seja responsável apenas pelas respostas dos objetos `JSON`. Ele vai servir para qualquer tipo de dado que vc queira recuperar, inclusive dados do banco:

**Controller 'Json.php'**:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Json extends CI_Controller {

    /**
    * Returns a JSON object
    **/
    function index() {
        $alert = $this->input->post();
        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($alert));
    }
}
```

Criado o `controller` que vai responder com os objetos `JSON`, crie os que vão usá-los:

**Controller 'Pages.php'**:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('pages/index');
    }
}
```

**View 'pages/index**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                //Comportamento do botao de envio
                $('#submit').click(function () {
                    submit();
                });
                //Alteracao do comportamento do formulario de envio
                $("#form").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            //Funcao que faz o request
            function submit() {
                //Envia um request POST para o method 'json/index';
                $.post(
                    $("#form").attr("action"),//Captura a action do FORM
                    $("#form").serialize(),//Captura os dados do FORM
                    //Captura a resposta do PHP
                    function (resp) {
                        //Alterando os valores em elementos especificos
                        $('#alert-msg').html('Classe invocada: '+resp.class);
                        $('#alert-title').html('Mostrando a classe para o elemento #alert');
                        //Muda a classe do elemento #alert
                        $("#alert").attr('class', resp.class);
                    }
                );              
                //Mostra o elemento #alert
                $('#alert').css('display', 'block');
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            /* Por padrao, oculta elementos com id = 'alert' */
            #alert{
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar"></nav>
        <div class="container">
            <p><b>Altere a classe do elemento #alert:</b></p>
            <div id="alert" role="alert">
                <strong id="alert-title">
                </strong> <div id="alert-msg"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <form action="json/index" id="form">
                    <select class="form-control" name="class">
                        <option value="alert alert-success">Success</option>
                        <option value="alert alert-info">Info</option>
                        <option value="alert alert-warning">Warning</option>
                        <option value="alert alert-danger">Danger</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="submit">Alterar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Observando o código constante da `view` vc vai perceber que o que importa, neste caso, é o `JavaScript`/`JQuery`. Ele é que vai tratar o comportamento do `form`, dos botões e a resposta obtida do `method` `json/index` e alterar os dados mostrados.

O código está comentado, e não deve ser difícil implementar ou alterar para atender às suas necessidades.